# How to prepare the ui dynamically at runtime in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have parsed one xml file using XMLResourceParser now I want to develop the UI based on values those I got from the parser.
My xml file says the co-ordainates for each element(4 values specifying the left,top,bottom,corner

For example you can have a look at this.

```
<root>
<panel bounds="0,0,500,500">
<label bounds="20,20,100,30">Hi</label>
<button bounds="130,20,100,30">i am button</button>
<panel bounds="0,40,300,300">
<label bounds="10,20,200,30">i am in</label>
</panel>
</panel>
</root>
```

here panel is my relative layout , label is textview and button is normal button

Comment: Your questions is not clear at all. Are you reading layout XML files?

Comment: I am parsing xml file and according to parsed results I want to construct the layout at runtime

Comment: Absolute layouts are deprecated. Whats the parent ViewGroup of this View with left, right, top and corner? And whats the exact attribute? android:left? I am not sure if there is an android:left

Comment: those left,top,bottom and right

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute layouts. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Comment: Dont want to use absolute layout :(

Comment: Then you have to create a custom view, and draw objects on the canvas based on the co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `AbsoluteLayout` and add all elements. For correct placing use `LayoutParams`:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = newView.getLayoutParams();
params.x = left;
params.y = top;
newView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Dont want to use the absolute layout :(

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` and margins, but it will be hard to cover all possible variants of (top-left) pair